# Describing an element of the normal subgroup $W=\cap_{g \in G} gHg^{-1}$ of the finite group $G$ where $H$ is a subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, normal-subgroups

I have proven that $W$ is a normal subgroup like this :

Let $w \in W$.

Then $w \in gHg^{-1} \; \forall \; g \in G.$

Let $g_1 \in G$ be arbitrary. Then $g_1 w g_1^{-1} \in g_1gHg^{-1}g_1^{-1} \; \forall \; g \in G \Rightarrow g_1 w g_1^{-1} \in g_2 H g_2^{-1}=W \; \forall \; g_2 \in G.$

That is for all $g \in G$, $gWg^{-1} \subseteq W$. Thus $W$ is normal.

---

**My question is :** If $w \in W$, then how to write $w$ in terms of some $g \in G$ and $h \in H$?

**I thought of this :** If $w \in W$, then for every $h \in H$ there exists a $g \in G$ such that $w=ghg^{-1}$. This is  because all elements in $W$ are of the form $ghg^{-1}$ for all $h$ and for all $g$.

But I'm still very much confused over this a long time and not sure. Am I right?

Comment: No you have your quantifiers mixed up. For every $w \in W$ and every $g \in G$, there exists $h \in H$ such that $w = ghg^{-1}$. But I do not understand what exactly you are asking. If you are given $w\in W$ and $g \in G$, then you can find $h$ using  $h = g^{-1}wg$

Comment: @DerekHolt Okay. I was confused exactly on quantifiers. If I wanted to start my proof of normality of $W$ with $w,h$ and $g$ then I would've to write $w$ in terms of $g$ & $h$ but with proper quantifiers. So, as you have said, if $w \in W$ then for every $g \in G$ there exists a $h \in H$ such that $w=ghg^{-1}$. It was the intersection sign that was making me confused to understand $w$.